# Oracle pl/sql -- how does the Rank() function evaluate

Tags: oracle

My (limited) understanding of the Rank() function is that if n rows match the partition criteria, based on the ordering, the first set of non matching rows gets a rank of 1, then that set of 1's gets added up for the next rank of rows.  How does it move to rank 2?  In the following dataset I have 3 rows of rank 9 (3 matching rows), and the next ranking is 12 (9+3 = 12), which I then have 2 rows of 12's (2 matching rows of rank 12) and the next rank is then 14.  I don't understand the rows of rank 1's, and the 2's.  What is the process of incrementing the ranks of those rows?

Here is my source code

```
select Pos_ID, work_city, organization
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY work_city ORDER BY organization) rnk
from DDTMS.POSITIONS
where pos_ID < 14800 order by rnk;
```

and here is a (partial) dataset result (I added the periods to keep it somewhat formatted for easier viewing - 1st row is a header row)

```
POS_ID  WORK_CITY___________    ORGANIZATION________    RNK
14741   QUANTICO............    HQ US MARINE CORPS..    1
14765   REDSTONE ARSENAL....    US ARMY AVN & MISSLE    1
14769   SAN DIEGO...........    SPACE & NAVAL WARFAR    1
14776   THE HAGUE...........    USD(COMPTROLLER)....    1
14790   VICKSBURG...........    U S ARMY ENGR RESEAR    1
14732   WARREN..............    US ARMY TANK-AUTOMOT    1
14777   WASHINGTON..........    HQUSACE MILITARY PRO    1
14774   WASHINGTON NAVY YARD    COMMANDER, NAVAL INS    1
14771   WRIGHT PATTERSON AFB    AF AUDIT AGENCY.....    1
14749   EGLIN AFB...........    AIR ARMAMENT........    2
14764   WRIGHT PATTERSON AFB    AF MUSEUM...........    2
14789   ARLINGTON...........    AS(LOGISTICS & MATER    2
14783   ABERDEEN PROV GRND..    USA EDGEWOOD CHEM AN    2
14779   FORT BELVOIR........    DLA LOGISTICS OPERAT    2
14735   WASHINGTON..........    NAVSEA HQ FIELD SUPP    2
14733   PENTAGON, ARLINGTON.    IMMEDIATE OFC OF CHI    2
14738   PENTAGON, ARLINGTON.    IMMEDIATE OFC OF CHI    2
14762   FORT MEADE..........    DISA, GIG OPERATIONS    2
14739   WASHINGTON NAVY YARD    PEO FOR SUBMARIN....    2
14737   ARLINGTON...........    ASD(ASIAN & PACIFIC.    3
14775   ABERDEEN PROV GRND..    USA HQ COMM ELECT CM    3
14731   FORT BELVOIR........    OFC OF THE CHIEF OF.    3
14729   ARLINGTON...........    DEFENSE SECURITY COO    4
14745   ARLINGTON...........    DIR, COST ASSESSMENT    5
14736   ARLINGTON...........    HQDA, ODCSLOG.......    6
14788   ARLINGTON...........    HQDA, OSA, OFC OF TH    7
14760   ARLINGTON...........    OASD (HOMELAND DEF &    8
14740   ARLINGTON...........    OASD (SO/LIC & INTER    9
14773   ARLINGTON...........    OASD (SO/LIC & INTER    9
14743   ARLINGTON...........    OASD (SO/LIC & INTER    9
14750   ARLINGTON...........    OASD(ISA)...........    12
14751   ARLINGTON...........    OASD(ISA)...........    12
14778   ARLINGTON...........    OFC ASST SECY OF ARM    14
14746   ARLINGTON...........    OFC DIR, ADMIN/MGMT.    15
14753   ARLINGTON...........    OFC GEN COUNSEL.....    16
14734   ARLINGTON...........    OFC SEC OF DEF......    17
14768   ARLINGTON...........    OFFICE OF NAVAL RESE    18
14781   ARLINGTON...........    ONI.................    19
14757   ARLINGTON...........    U S AIR FORCE.......    20
14763   ARLINGTON...........    U S AIR FORCE HQ....    21
```

Comment: I left out the rnk alias and order by on the outer part of the query.  Just updated that.

Comment: The way I think of `RANK()` is that it returns the number of records that are earlier/smaller than the current record, plus 1. So rank=1 means that there are zero records earlier/smaller than the current record; rank=2 means that there is exactly 1 record earlier/smaller than the current record; rank 12 means there are 11 records earlier/smaller than the current record.

Answer (score 0):

Rank is independent for each partition. So every partition will have a rank of one. Partitions with at least two rows and no tie at rank one will have a rank of two.

It might be clearer if you ordered your results to match the partitioning and ordering of the rank function:

```
select Pos_ID, work_city, organization
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY work_city ORDER BY organization)
from DDTMS.POSITIONS
where pos_ID < 14800
order by work_city, organization;
```